# How can I align the text size in tkinter Canvas with scrollbar motions?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Hello I'm korean student currently studying in Korea.

```
class Layout(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=750, background="bisque")
        self.xsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.ysb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.ysb.set, xscrollcommand=self.xsb.set)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,1000,1000))

        self.xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
        self.ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #self.canvas.create_text(50,10, text="Click and drag to move the canvas\nScroll to zoom.")

        # This is what enables using the mouse:
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.move_start)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move_move)
        #linux scroll
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-4>", self.zoomerP)
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-5>", self.zoomerM)
        #windows scroll
        self.canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>",self.zoomer)

    #move
    def move_start(self, event):
        self.canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)
    def move_move(self, event):
        self.canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)

    #windows zoom
    def zoomer(self,event):
        if (event.delta > 0):
            self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 1.1, 1.1)
        elif (event.delta < 0):
            self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 0.9, 0.9)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    #linux zoom
    def zoomerP(self,event):
        self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 1.1, 1.1)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))
    def zoomerM(self,event):
        self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 0.9, 0.9)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))
```

as you can see the codes above
I have made the codes to display the Canvas widget.
and I have also aligned the scrollbars with the materials displayed in the canvas widget.

```
 monitor1.canvas.create_rectangle(50 + 200*(l-3*ll) + 800*(k % 3), 250 + 150*(ll) + 150*(vertical_append//3 + 2*kk), 90 + 200*(l-3*ll) + 800*(k % 3), 300 + 150*(ll) + 150*(vertical_append//3 + 2*kk) + 10*(int(each_info[5]) - 4), fill = "green")
                monitor1.canvas.create_rectangle(90 + 200*(l-3*ll) + 800*(k % 3), 245 + 150*(ll) + 150*(vertical_append//3 + 2*kk), 110 + 200*(l-3*ll) + 800*(k % 3), 305 + 150*(ll) + 150*(vertical_append//3 + 2*kk) + 10*(int(each_info[5]) - 4), fill = "red")
                monitor1.canvas.create_rectangle(110 + 200*(l-3*ll) + 800*(k % 3), 250 + 150*(ll) + 150*(vertical_append//3 + 2*kk), 150 + 200*(l-3*ll) + 800*(k % 3), 300 + 150*(ll) + 150*(vertical_append//3 + 2*kk) + 10*(int(each_info[5]) - 4), fill = "green")
                    
                # Labelling    
                monitor1.canvas.create_text(70 + 200*(l - 3*ll) + 800*(k % 3), 275 + 5*(int(each_info[5]) - 4) + 150*(ll) + 150*(vertical_append//3 + 2*kk), text = each_info[1], font =("Helvetica", 10)) 
                monitor1.canvas.create_text(100 + 200*(l - 3*ll) + 800*(k % 3), 270 + 5*(int(each_info[5]) - 4) + 150*(ll) + 150*(vertical_append//3 + 2*kk), text = each_info[2], font = ("Helvetica", 10))
                monitor1.canvas.create_text(130 + 200*(l - 3*ll) + 800*(k % 3), 275 + 5*(int(each_info[5]) - 4) + 150*(ll) + 150*(vertical_append//3 + 2*kk), text = each_info[3], font = ("Helvetica", 10))
                monitor1.canvas.create_text(110 + 200*(l - 3*ll) + 800*(k % 3), 235 + 150*(ll) + 150*(vertical_append//3 + 2*kk), text = each_info[0] + " " + each_info[4], font = ("Helvetica", 10))
                monitor1.canvas.create_text(110 + 200*(l - 3*ll) + 800*(k % 3), 205 + 150*(ll) + 150*(vertical_append//3 + 2*kk), text = key, font = ("Helvetica", 10))
                monitor1.canvas.create_text(110 + 200*(l - 3*ll) + 800*(k % 3), 220 + 150*(ll) + 150*(vertical_append//3 + 2*kk), text = "width: " + each_info[5], font = ("Helvetica", 10))
```

as you can see the codes above
I have created the rectangles and texts above

[rectanges & text in canvas before zoom out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuUxz.png)
[rectanges & text in canvas after zoom out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKHWu.png)

and as you can see in the images of png formats,
the rectangles in the canvas widgets are aligned well with the scrollbar motions
they get smaller as I zoom out with scroll bar
they get bigger as I zoom in with scroll bar

but the texts in the canvas widgets are not aligned with the scrollbar motions

what can I do to align the text widgets created in the canvas with the scrollbar motions

Comment: Please take the effort to paste the code. It is really hard for us to help you when you post image of the code

Comment: See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) for reasons **not** to do it.

Comment: According to the document on [`canvas.scale`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M79): *"Note that some items have only a single pair of coordinates (e.g., text, images and windows) and so scaling of them by this command can only move them around."*